# Open an childview from the position of listview

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

I have a listview which has 10 rows and which is scrollable. Now what i need is

1) By clicking each row am opening a child listview in the same window but all these are opening at the top. Instead i would like to open the views near the row and i want my parent view not to get hided. Eg. if i click 5th row new textview should be open near that row like here.
[image: ()]

2) For row selection in listview am using selector but my problem is main view is still in the selected state after am moving to the child row.
Instead i want the main view to be normal once i moved to child view and when am returning back and when i press back button at that time my main views row
needs to be selected.

Help me in achieving the same..

Comment: Are you opening a dialog on list item click?

Comment: no am opening textview on item click

Comment: what do you mean by "am opening textview" ?

Comment: @pskink i edited my question. when i click an item i need to open a child listview which shows related details about parent listview. Hope my question is clear.

Comment: @All is well you should put text-view to the each of the row and maintain it's visibility on row click.i.e on item click u have to show text-view below clicked item and hide it after click item again.

Comment: @Indiandroid am doing the same, what i want is i need to display my child view exactly at the position equal to its parent as like in above fig. not at the top of the view

Comment: Have u tried implementing the same using Fragments ?

Comment: so you want to show a TextView or a ListView?

Comment: Try Implementing StackScrollView Using Fragments https://github.com/raweng/Android-Stack-Scroll-View

Comment: Use expendable listview ?

Comment: @Yume117 i need my childview to be open in next window but in expandable view, it will open at same window

Comment: @SoftwareSainath i don't know how to implement the same with fragment, i tried but couldn't can u give an example of opening child listview from parentview through fragment

Comment: Then you have 2 solution, pen a new activity, OR use fragment and replace the listview by another listview

Comment: @pskink yes i need to show the child listview by clicking the parent listview rows.

Comment: Go through the tutorial for Fragments http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html

Comment: @Yume117 i want the parent view to be stable and don't want to hide it when childviews gets displayed. Can u give an example

Comment: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Fragments_in_Android_-_A_Worked_Example

Comment: i cannot achieve my child view in the expected place without using fragment? i did everything and only position and selector are the small issues here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Resolved my issue by placing it in Relative layout and here is my code..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="147dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        />
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="147dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
       />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this will help someone :-)

Answer (score 0):

THE FRAGMENT CONTAINER :

```
public class FragmentFolderList extends SherlockFragment{
    protected AdapterFolderList     _adapter;
    protected ListView              _listView;
    protected View                  _view;
    public static final String      BACKSTACKCATEGORY   = "backStackCat";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        _view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        _listView = (ListView) _view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        return _view;
    }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            _adapter = new AdapterFolderList();
            _listView.setAdapter(_adapter);
            _listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        }

    protected void moveToDirectory(int where) {
            FragmentDirectoriesList fragment = new FragmentDirectoriesList();
            Bundle param = new Bundle();
            param.putInt("position", where);
            fragment.setArguments(param);
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_annuaire, fragment).addToBackStack(BACKSTACKCATEGORY).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        moveToDirectory(position);
    }
}
```

THE LAYOUT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at what you describe, I think what you need is an `ExpandableListView` instead of a normal `ListView`, check out this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Comment: I don't want my child view on the same window. I need it to get open at next window. Can u tell me in expandable listview instead of opening in same window can we expand the view to the next window as described in the fig?